# Move-spuser doesn't replace user

Tags: powershell, stsadm, spuser

In sharepoint 2013 i need to replace a user by an other.
For this i use:

```
Move-SPUser -Identity "DOMAIN\JaneDoe" -NewAlias "Domain\JaneSmith" -IgnoreSID
```

I give permission on a site to JaneDoe puting him in a group.
After executing the command the user is remove from the group so he doesn't have anymore access but new user doesn't have access in his place!
If i get the permission again to JaneDoe his name is now JaneSmith

Could you give me a sample to replace a user by an other like stsadm -o migrateuser in SP2007

**Solution:**

$user = Get-SPUser -Identity "i:0#.w|domain\janedoe" -Web http://webUrl
Move-SPUser -Identity $user -NewAlias ":i:0#.w|domain\janesmith" -IgnoreSid

Answer (score 2):

The proper use of this cmdlet is:

```
$user = Get-SPUser -Identity "i:0#.w|domain\janedoe" -Web http://webUrl
Move-SPUser -Identity $user -NewAlias "domain\janesmith" -IgnoreSid
```

The Get-SPUser example is using Windows Claims (drop the `i:0#.w|` if not using Windows Claims) and the -Web is a Site Collection where the user is present in the User Information List.

Comment: Thanks Effectively i retrieve user and then i use move-spuser as you did but the result is the same. It removes old user permission but doesn't give permission to the new one

Comment: Get the new user into the `$user` variable using the same method about and validate the SystemUserKey matches the SID of the object in Active Directory.

Comment: I had to add " :i:0#.w|" before login name in parameter -NewAlias